# Nginx rewrite for multiple entry point

Tags: nginx

I have a structure like this.

- project root

  - entry_point1

    - index.html
  - entry_point2

    - index.html
  - entry_point3

    - index.html

It works out of the box, when I route to mydomain/entry_point1 it serves the right index.html

But what if I want to route the **root(/)** of the domain or any other unrecognized route to a specific entry point?
For example:

> mydomain/
>
> mydomain/some/path mydomain/some/other/path

All these paths must be redirected to mydomain/entry_point3

But obviously routes like:

> mydomain/entry_point1/some/resource

Won't be redirected

How can I achieve this?

I'm also using *react router* so routes like mydomain/entry_point1/path/to/resource will be rewritten to the index file of the entry point

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I ended up with the following configuration:

```
server {
  root path/to/folder;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name mydomain;

  location ~^\/entry1\.* {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /entry1/index.html;
  }

  location ~^\/entry2\.* {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /entry2/index.html;
  }

  location ~^\/entry3\.* {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /entry3/index.html;
  }

  location ~* {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /entry3/index.html;
  }
}
```

The problem now is that when i route to mydomain/ it redirects me to: mydomain/entry3/entry3/entry3/....

Other than this, it works perfectly.

When i route to **mydomain/(entry1|entry2|entry3)/some/resource**  it serves the (entry1|entry2|entry3)/index.html

When i route to **mydomain/some/other/path** it serves the entry3/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
  listen 8081;

  location ~^\/entry2\.* {
    return 301 $scheme://www.entrypoint2.com$request_uri;
  }
  location ~^\/entry1\.* {
    return 301 $scheme://www.entrypoint1.com$request_uri;
  }
  location ~* {
    return 301 $scheme://www.entrypoint1.com/;
  }
}
```

curl -X GET "http://badasse.com:8081/entry1" -I => http://www.entrypoint1.com/entry1

curl -X GET "http://badasse.com:8081/entry1/sdfsdf" -I => http://www.entrypoint1.com/entry1/sdfsdf

curl -X GET "http://badasse.com:8081/entry2" -I => http://www.entrypoint2.com/entry2

curl -X GET "http://badasse.com:8081/entry2/sdfdsf" -I => http://www.entrypoint2.com/entry2/sdfsdf

curl -X GET "http://badasse.com:8081/esdfdsf" -I => http://www.entrypoint1.com/entry1

Comment: Actually the domain should be the same, I don't have a domain for each entry point. But i understand how it works

Comment: It just an example to show how regex can works with nginx :)

Comment: Yeah that was useful, now I have another problem, check the edit in the question please!